# Azure Deployment: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I deployed my multi-tier application to azure. It was working perfectly, but now when I try to deploying it, it shows an error saying:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MySomething.dll' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)
```

I checked other answers, but all of them dealing with IIS. Azure Web Apps IIS cannot be accessed directly. How can I resolve this?

Comment: what is the dll name??

Comment: the dll is being used by another process. Try restarting VS. If it doesn't work, try restarting the PC. it should work. Or if you know which process is using it, just terminate the process.

Comment: for the assembly set "copy local" property to true

Comment: The problem doesn't happen on my local machine. It works fine locally. When I deploy it to web server (particularly azure), it breaks.

Comment: @Saeid, Could you check whether  this file is existed on Azure server? You could check it via FTP

Comment: It exists. Actually I just noticed the issue rises on local IIS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, this issue happened because of caching. Removing the bin/obj directories alongside the IIS Express cache folder fixed the issue.